# Quillen pairs / $\infty$-adjunctions / adjunctions of homotopy categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

Some of the examples of $\infty$-categories are those arising from model categories. I would like to ask: what is the relationship between Quillen adjunctions between model categories and adjoint pairs in the $\infty$-setting?

1. More precisely, let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ be two simplicially    enriched model categories, is it true that every adjoint pair of    $\infty$-functors between $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ comes from a    Quillen pair?
2. More generally, what can be said about the relationship between: i) the category of Quillen pairs between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$  ii) the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-adjoint pairs between    $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ (abusing the notation), and iii) the category of adjunctions  between $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal{A}$ and    $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal{B}$ ? (where    $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal{A}$ is the localization of $\mathcal{A}$    at the weak equivalences)
3. Same question with "adjunction" replaced by "equivalence"

For example, I know that in general not every equivalence between $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal{A}$ and $\operatorname{Ho}\mathcal{B}$ arises from a Quillen adjunction. You can feel free to add assumptions / modify the question to make it more interesting or answerable if it is not such in the present form.

Answer (score 6):

> More precisely, let A,B be two simplicially enriched model categories, is it true that every adjoint pair of ∞-functors between A,B comes from a Quillen pair?

Assuming the model categories are combinatorial (but not necessarily simplicial), this is true up to a Quillen equivalence,
i.e., every ∞-adjunction is induced by composing Quillen adjunctions with Quillen equivalences.

This is essentially Theorem 1.1 in [arXiv:2110.04679](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04679).

In fact, a zigzag of a simple form (a Quillen equivalence followed by a Quillen adjunction) is sufficient: replace both combinatorial model categories with model categories of simplicial presheaves using Dugger's construction, and as long as the underlying sites have sufficiently many objects, the given Quillen functor will be induced by a functor of underlying sites.

Without using zigzags, this is likely false and counterexamples should not be too difficult to construct.

In the converse direction, every Quillen adjunction induces an ∞-adjunction.  (Several references can be found in the cited paper.)

In general, there is no way to lift adjunctions between homotopy categories, since too much information is discarded.

Comment: Thank you very much! Honestly I thought it was much simpler. I will have to delve into your paper and come back with some questions. But first I would like to ask: you say you need to have some condition on the number of objects in the site, but this is only to have a "simpler" zig-zag right? the general fact that any  ∞-adjunction is induced by composing Quillen adjunctions with Quillen equivalences is true without further assumptions except that the model categories are combinatorial, do I understand correctly? So in general it will be a longer zig-zag of the form adj - equiv - adj -equiv -

Comment: Regarding the thing about the simpler zig-zag. Let's take for simplicity the case where A and B are already categories of simplicial presheaves on some small category. I can use the universal property of simplicial presheaves to show that any Quillen adj comes from functors from the underlying sites. This is all good and fine. So why the condition about enough objects? And it is not clear how does this relate to functors between the $\infty$-categories?

Comment: To be more clear: I understand well how one can replace combinatorial model cats with localizations of simplicial presheaves using Dugger's machinery (this is why I stated my question already in the less general case of simplicial categories), what I don't know is how to relate Quillen adjunctions and $\infty$-adjunctions. I would be even already satisfied to understand even the simpler case where A and B are just categories of simplicial presheaves.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom: Roughly, the construction takes as an input a left adjoint functor F:C→D, picks a regular cardinal κ such that C and D are κ-presentable and F preserves κ-compact objects.  Then F is the κ-Ind-completion of its restriction to κ-presentable objects.  Thus, the problem has been reduced to a problem about small quasicategories, and you can use standard tools to rectify such a functor to an honest functor between small simplicial categories (say).  Then you can take simplicial presheaves on these and extract the Ind-completions as model categories.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom: This construction converts a left adjoint functor between presentable quasicategories to a left Quillen functor between combinatorial model categories.  If you now compose with left Quillen equivalences constructed by Dugger, you get a zigzag consisting of a left Quillen equivalence and a left Quillen functor presenting your original functor between quasicategories.

Answer (score 3):

(1) No, it is not true. There are examples of adjunctions between $\infty$-categories that do not come from Quillen adjunctions. More often, they come from zigzags of Quillen adjunctions, at least if everything in sight is presentable.

(2) There is an embedding of the $\infty$-category of (left) Quillen functors $lQFun(A,B)$ into the $\infty$-category of left adjoint $\infty$-functors $Fun_\infty(A,B)$. But it's not an equivalence, for the reason I said above. Similarly, every $\infty$-adjunction gives rise to an adjunction of homotopy categories, but not every such adjunction comes from an $\infty$-adjunction. Explicit counterexamples are well-known (e.g., Muro has written about this).

(3) Same issues with "equivalence" everywhere. Again, in presentable settings, $\infty$-equivalences give rise to zigzags of Quillen equivalences.

Comment: thank you! it would be extremely helpful to me if you could add references?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to. But teaching is kinda full-on right now so it might be a minute.

Comment: I found a brief moment to add a reference. The following paper shows an example of two model categories that are not Quillen equivalent but their homotopy categories are equivalent: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/dugger.shipley.curious.example.pdf

Comment: The following paper shows that every Quillen adjunction (resp. equivalence) yields an adjunction (resp. equivalence) of associated $\infty$-categories: http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2016/22-4.html

Comment: Example 4.3 here shows a bit of what can go wrong if you leave the realm of presentable $\infty$-categories / combinatorial model categories: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08094.pdf